# how to simulate a real mobile internet connection within android emulator

Tags: android, connection, emulation

I'd like to know if there is some method to let emulator behave like real device when accessing internet. Before any operation that requires internet access I usually check connection like this

```
public boolean internet(){
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
    }
```

but on real device and when mobile reception is poor, internet connection isn't actually available thought internet() returned true. It's not just a latency issue or a low speed problem, the request it's not sent at all (or never get the response, I don't know). Currently I'm getting this problem when calling

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(new URI(url));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
```

and have no idea how to debug it on a real device. I'm pretty sure it is mobile internet connection's fault, because I have no problem when the same device is connected via wi-fi.
I thought that setting httpclient socket and connection timeouts would solve the problem, but I still get crashes.

Comment: Please add a log of the crash

Comment: @Mr.Me how can I get the log from the device?

Comment: you can see the log throw logcat when connected to PC. else you will have to write your own log methods, maybe to write any exception output to your sdcard or something

Answer (score 3):

You can emulate this using some parameteres when launching the emulator.
They are all documented here:
[Android Emulator](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html).

In this case the parameters you want are:

`-netdelay <delay`

`-netspeed <speed>`

They set the latency and speed of the connection your emulator uses.

For any other issues, you may need to post your logcat log, it may be that connects and in the mid of the request the connection drops and the device get disconnected.

Comment: these are the same parameters that can be set from eclipse adt ddms perspective, aren't they? I think the connection actually drop, but in the system bar I can still see mobile network, 3g or h or h+ as if it was connected

Comment: yep, you can set those from eclipse.
About the dropping connection , i have experimented those as connections on my country are not that good.
Sometimes Gtalk does not even notice there is no network available anymore , so the most you can AFAIK is a timeout and handle the errors gracefully.